# geogebra-classic not found

Tags: package-management, software-installation

In accordance with the instructions given by https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Installation, I tried installing geogebra by first using `sudo apt-add-repository -u 'deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main'`, and then `sudo apt install geogebra-classic`, but when I run the last command, I get the error message "Unable to locate package geogebra-classic". Any tips?

Answer (score 6):

You have add their GPG key by

```
wget https://static.geogebra.org/linux/office@geogebra.org.gpg.key -O - | sudo apt-key add
```

and then rerun update and install package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geogebra-classic
```

Comment: There's an issue with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:
https://www.reddit.com/r/geogebra/comments/ypj1bg/geogebra_5_classic_package_package_repo_key/

Answer (score 1):

First, add the GPG key, then the repository, and finally install by these commands:

```
$ wget https://static.geogebra.org/linux/office@geogebra.org.gpg.key -O - | sudo apt-key add
$ sudo apt-add-repository -u 'deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main' 
$ sudo apt install geogebra-classic
```

Thus the latest Geogebra will be installed.

Comment: There's an issue with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:
https://www.reddit.com/r/geogebra/comments/ypj1bg/geogebra_5_classic_package_package_repo_key/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to try [GeoGebra Discovery](https://github.com/kovzol/geogebra-discovery) (which is maintained by me) that may address some Linux related issues. It is based on GeoGebra 5.0.641.0 (the classic Java-based user interface). It can be installed as a snap: https://snapcraft.io/geogebra-discovery.

Comment: The linked snap page shows you're the packager for this snap. Please disclose that into your answer, otherwise this can be considered spam. (This also goes for your other answer promoting this snap)