# Why does the 'Import Key File' button in Lubuntu 20.04 Software Sources | Authentication dialog not do anything?

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, gnupg

*Why does the 'Import Key File' button in Lubuntu 20.04 Software Sources | Authentication dialog not do anything?*

I downloaded a key file for Geogebra's repository.  I believe that when I click Preferences | Software Sources | Authentication | Add Key File, I should get a file dialog which lets me choose the key file.  However nothing happens when I press the button.

I have never used this functionality before, so maybe I am doing something wrong.  The manual glosses over the issue, which makes me very suspicious though.

I am using Lubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Question text should provide all details, as some devices & browser setups don't allow the title to be shown when reading your question description. I can't quite make out your description (it's unclear; title says it all? but title isn't visible?), and don't want two windows open so I can read the title from the main 'question selection' window.  Your question description should be complete (unless you're happy for only some users to have a chance of understanding & answering...)

Comment: If the Lubuntu manual isn't complete; it's only because there are very few people who step up and help write any documentation for it. If you'd like to help make it more complete; we'd love for that too, so please feel free to step up and help (the one person doing the manual would love the help) https://lubuntu.me/links/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [geogebra-classic not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279948/geogebra-classic-not-found)

Comment: @guiverc I have added the title in the question body.  The problem is not that the Lubuntu manual is incomplete, rather that the button does nothing at all.  Lack of any mention in the manual makes me suspect developers know it does not work, but I could easily be wrong there.

Comment: Developers don't write the manual, it is written largely by a single person in their free time, and the desktop being documented is constantly changing (new buttons, new features, even some removed) keep occurring yet their isn't time for the writer to return & check an already documented section, unless or until a bug or request is filed asking that page/section of the manual to be corrected/updated.   More help is needed.

Comment: Sigh - I never said the lack of the documentation in the manual was the problem.  I want to know if the button should do something, because for me, on my system, it does not.  If it works for everybody else, then I need to find out why it does not for me.  If the button's functionality was never implemented then I can just give up.

Comment: I was responding to "*Lack of any mention in the manual makes me suspect developers know it does not work*" where the developers don't write the manual; it's written by another person, and I'm betting the button didn't exist when that section was written (we're on our sixth cycle of LXQt meaning currently six versions of LXQt have been used) and the one person doesn't have time to research and write up all the changes (there were well over 30 on the last LXQt update alone) and if there isn't time.. it'll get done when it's done... thus more help is always welcome if you'd like to help.